# why am getting error with MongoClient()?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

Actually am new to this mongodb.

Here mongo was visible on localhost and phpinfo(). for

`http://127.0.0.1:27017/`

also getting like "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port." .
From command prompt also am able to run mongo.

But still am getting an error while using Mongo()/MongoClient from program.

```
Deprecated: main(): The Mongo class is deprecated, please use the MongoClient class in C:\wamp\www\mongo\new.php on line 2

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message ' in C:\wamp\www\mongo\new.php on line 4
( ! ) MongoConnectionException: Failed to connect to: example.com:27017: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\wamp\www\mongo\new.php on line 4
```

How i can solve these issues?

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is usually caused when using the deprecated Mongo class, which has long been replaced with the MongoClient class, the new MongoClient class requires you to create a connection like this `$m = new MongoClient();`previously using the old class it would have looked like this `$m = new Mongo();`

If you would like to read more on this http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php